# Chart.js ERROR: Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Tags: php, jquery, chart.js

Estoy intentando mostrar un gráfico de líneas con Chart.js y en este caso me muestra el error "**Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item**" y no encuentro el motivo.

El codigo html es:

```
<div align='center'><canvas id='grafico_ventas' width='280vw' height='240vw'></canvas></div>
```

y el codigo jquery es

```
var ano = "2020"
var ano_ant = "2019"

var ctx_gp = document.getElementById("grafico_ventas");

var grafico_ventas = new Chart(ctx_gp, {

    data: {
        labels : ["ENE","FEB","MAR","ABR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AGO","SEP","OCT","NOV","DIC"],
        datasets: [{
            type: 'line',
            label: ano,
            data :[[12654.13,11889.39,7660.59,6284.87,5959.92,4786.71,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,0.4)'],
            borderWidth: 1
        }, {
            label: ano_ant,
            type: 'line',
            data: [[12516.06,11217.55,9859.06,11071.59,10541.18,9999.59,12947.56,17804.7,10028.87,12695.56,11918.95,9515.36]],
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(113, 179, 124, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: ['rgba(113, 179, 124,1)'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(113, 179, 124,0.4)'],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,                   
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

¿alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas pasar el `context 2d` del Canvas, no el Canvas como tal.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("grafico_ventas");
var ctx_gp = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Cambiando eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Ya lo había probado. Al incluirlo, me muestra otro error:
"Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function"